# Entity Framework Linq vb get list of users based on curent user account list or belong to no account

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

This code lists what users belong to the same accounts as the current user.

```
entity.users.Where(Function(b) b.accounts.Any(Function(c) c.users.Any(Function(d) d.user_id = MySession.Current.user_id))).ToList
```

What i cant work out, is how would i get it to return users that belong to no account groups as well as users that have the same accounts as current user?

This code is for certain admin users to only admin there own accounts and to manage new users that dont belong to an account yet.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to add an `... Not b.accounts.Any() OrElse ...` to the `Where` clause, like so:

```
entity.users.Where(Function(b) _
    Not b.accounts.Any() OrElse _
        b.accounts.Any(Function(c) c.users.Any(Function(d) _
            d.user_id = MySession.Current.user_id))).ToList()
```